# Mobile layout not adjusted to screen size

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, frontend

I have created a website and developed the frontend to be resposnisve with the help of the Firfox Developer Tools (to test on different screen sizes). Now that I have deployed my web app, I am facing a problem.

On mobile devices, the layout is not as it was on the developer tools, with the same screen size. The page is having a resolution of 1920px x 1080px and is just zoomed in (see image)

[image]

I have use this tag, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I have made all of my css responsive and the problem comes only, that the page on the mobile layout is not the same size as the device. So i would like to know, how can I adjust my page, to be the same size as the device?

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/FloHop/h8ruo0sv/1/)** is a JsFiddle with the **base** layout of my website 
**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/FloHop/8gmdqkfe/5/)** is the JsFiddle with the actual **content** of the website

The website is available under: https://piaweirather.de/, test it on desktop and on mobile and you will see what i mean.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need any more infos, please don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Can you post your code as a fiddle here? Would be helpful if we can actually see what is the problem here

Comment: There is a typo, you have written "widt", and not "width", in `content` attribute.

Comment: Thanks to pointing the typo out. But this was only in my question, not in my code. I fixed the typo in the question.

Comment: you need to add some code, so we can find out where the problem is. In this code which you've written, is nothing wrong.

Comment: As others have said, you should add the code to your page so that we can help answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for you suggestion, I have added a second JsFiddle with the content of the page. I use Django, the first Fiddle is the base, and the second Fiddle is the content inserted into the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, I have found the problem.
It seems as `overflow: hidden;` and 
 `position: absolute;` don't go well together.  
After removing this part in my CSS file, the problem dissapeared:

```
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you need the functionality of `position: absolute`, I would recommend using `position: fixed` instead.

tldr: Don't combine `overflow: hidden` and `position: absolute`, if you want to target the mobile market.